# Display Null Value or Zero-Valued Data from Textfile in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, file-upload

This code functions by reading textfile content, manipulate the data in it and display the output in a textbox.

```
 using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                string filenameDate = FileUpload1.FileName.Substring(15, 2);
                Dictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
                    {

                        //int readedLineTime = Convert.ToInt32(readedLine.Substring(09, 02));
                        string sDate = readedLine.Substring(0, 11);

                        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
                        countedChars = collection.Count;




                        if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(sDate))
                        {
                            dMyobject.Add(sDate, collection.Count);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dMyobject[sDate] = dMyobject[sDate] + collection.Count;
                        }


                    }
                    textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
                    i++;
                }
                txtContent.Text = textfileContent;
                lblLineCount.Text = i.ToString();
                //Label1.Text =  this.TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
                lblFileDate.Text = filenameDate;




                foreach (var item in dMyobject)
                {
                    textfileOutput += (item.Key + "  " + item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                    //  textfileOutput += (item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                txtOutput.Text = textfileOutput;



            }
```

each line in the textfile contains a date and series of pattern. this code read each lines separated by dates and count the total occurrence of a pattern, in this example, counting the pattern "D;" and summarize its total per Date (lines with same date should be summed-up). For example

[image]

running the code will give this **current output**

```
2016-12-01 - 7 
2016-12-02 - 9
2016-12-03 - 5
2016-12-05 - 1
```

**My Objective and desired output should include in the output the date with NULL VALUE. In my example, there was no 2016-12-04 record, **expected output should have displayed the date still and display 0 or blank** such as:**

```
2016-12-01 - 7 
2016-12-02 - 9
2016-12-03 - 5
2016-12-04 - 0
2016-12-05 - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

```
using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
    string filenameDate = "test";
    string textfileContent = string.Empty;
    int i = 0;
    string textfileOutput = string.Empty;
    Dictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
    {
        var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
        {
            string sDate = readedLine.Substring(0, 11).Trim();

            MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
            if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(sDate))
            {
                dMyobject.Add(sDate, collection.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                dMyobject[sDate] = dMyobject[sDate] + collection.Count;
            }


        }
        textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
        i++;
    }

    var date = DateTime.Parse(dMyobject.First().Key);
    var beginOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    var days = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (var x = 0; x < DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month); x++)
    {
        days.Add(beginOfMonth.AddDays(x).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 0);
    }

    foreach (var item in days)
    {
        textfileOutput += (dMyobject.ContainsKey(item.Key) ? (item.Key + "  " + dMyobject[item.Key]) : (item.Key + "  0")) + Environment.NewLine;
    }

}
```

So the the last bit of code first creates the date ranges that are needed by picking a date from your `Dictionary` and iterating to the last day of that month. It then checks your matches and counts against the date ranges and if there is a match, use the updated count instead of `0`.

Comment: You are correct, apologies, please see my edited question @johanP

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for this, but the only thing this may lack is what if the very first date  is null for example, dec 1 is null, it will not display it

Comment: that's the only thing remaining

Comment: it should always start with the first day regardless if it's null. @johanP

Comment: Also sir the last date, to be specific, 1 - 31 should be the default dates with value

Answer (score 1):

In your upload file, there have 2016-12-04 line, you just edit you `Regex` for got all char and count the total score.

**fix 1**:Check whether the continuous time.

```
    using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
                {
                    string filenameDate = FileUpload1.FileName.Substring(15, 2);
                    SortedDictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(); //this is a dictionary sorted by key 
            DateTime? startDatetime = null, endDatetime = null;//got mininum and maxinum dates, at late will be check  the continuous time

                    while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
                        {

                            string sDate = readedLine.Substring(0, 11).Trim();
                    DateTime date;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(sDate, out date))
                    {
                        if (startDatetime.HasValue == false)
                            startDatetime = date;
                        endDatetime = date;
//got start date and end date
//if date does not from big to small
//here need compare bwteen date and endDatetime
                    }


                MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, "(?<c>[A-Z]+);");

                            if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(sDate))
                            {
                                dMyobject.Add(sDate, GetTotal(collection));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dMyobject[sDate] = dMyobject[sDate] + GetTotal(collection);
                            }


                        }
                        textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        i++;
                    }

    //here is check the continuous time
            if (startDatetime.HasValue && endDatetime.HasValue)
            {
                for (var dt = startDatetime; dt.Value.CompareTo(endDatetime) <= 0; dt = dt.Value.AddDays(1))
                {
                    string key = dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        dMyobject[key] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


                    txtContent.Text = textfileContent;
                    lblLineCount.Text = i.ToString();
                    //Label1.Text =  this.TextBox1.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
                    lblFileDate.Text = filenameDate;




                    foreach (var item in dMyobject)
                    {
                        textfileOutput += (item.Key + "  " + item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                        //  textfileOutput += (item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    txtOutput.Text = textfileOutput;



                }


    //this method is a new method, it got total score, and if you rule chanage you can set `D` +1, `A` +2 etc.
            private int GetTotal(MatchCollection collection)
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> point = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                point["D"] = 1;
                point["A"] = 0;

                int total = 0;
                foreach (Match m in collection)
                {
                    string str = m.Groups["c"].Value;
                    if (point.ContainsKey(str))
                        total += point[str];
                }
                return total;
            }
```

Comment: This does not get the desired output because it sums up all the total "D" and 'A" occurrence, as what the question states it should count the "D;" occurrence PER DATE , please see the desired output, Thanks

Comment: I was fixed it. Use my code you can definition every letter's point, for example: if every `D` add 1 point, every `A`  add 2 point and every `O`  deduct 1 point. Then use my code satisfy these easily.

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments JohanP Answer, code is working fine expect date sub-string is wrong in original code and there are no issue with Dictionary 0 Value

Comment: There's lacking, that's when the very first date is null.

Answer (score 0):

JohanP's answer is a big help, but there are limitations because it also needs to write the first dates when it is null. So based from his answer, I have come up with this codes.

```
using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {

            Dictionary<string, int> dMyobject = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                var readedLine = stRead.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(readedLine))
                {
                    //int readedLineTime = Convert.ToInt32(readedLine.Substring(11, 02));
                    string sDate = readedLine.Substring(11, 2);

                    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"D;");
                    countedChars = collection.Count;


                    if (!dMyobject.Keys.Contains(sDate))
                    {
                        dMyobject.Add(sDate, collection.Count);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dMyobject[sDate] = dMyobject[sDate] + collection.Count;
                    }
                }
                textfileContent += readedLine + Environment.NewLine;
                i++;
            }
            txtContent.Text = textfileContent;
            lblLineCount.Text = i.ToString();



            var prevDate = string.Empty; 
            int tester = 01;

            foreach (var item in dMyobject)
            {
                int testCorrectStart = Convert.ToInt32(item.Key) - tester;
                if (testCorrectStart == 0)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prevDate))
                    {
                        var cur = Int32.Parse(item.Key); // convert current key into int
                        var prev = Int32.Parse(prevDate);
                        int dayDiff = cur - prev;
                        for (var x = 0; x < dayDiff - 1; x++) // run through day difference, add it to the last date that was added
                        {

                            textfileOutput += ((prev + (x + 1)).ToString() + "  0" + Environment.NewLine);

                        }
                    }

                    textfileOutput += (item.Key + "  " + item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                    prevDate = item.Key;
                    tester++;
                }

                else
                {

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tester.ToString()))
                    {
                        var cur = Int32.Parse(item.Key); // convert current key into int
                        var prev = Int32.Parse(tester.ToString());
                        int dayDiff = cur - prev;
                        for (var x = 0; x < dayDiff ; x++) // run through day difference, add it to the last date that was added
                        {

                            textfileOutput += ("0" +(prev + x).ToString() + "  0" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                    textfileOutput += (item.Key + "  " + item.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
                    prevDate = item.Key;
                    tester = Convert.ToInt32(prevDate) + 1;
                }
            }
            txtOutput.Text = textfileOutput;
        }
```

you can test its correcteness